# Python3 calls function directly from class name. Utility function? Static function? Or implicit instantiate an object

Tags: python-3.x, singleton, static-methods, utility-method

I am looking the following python3 code:

```
class MyClass(MyAbstractClass):
      :
    def my_fun1(self, input1):
         :
        return result
```

Then at other part of the codes, MyClass is used like:

```
output = MyClass().my_fun1(input1)
```

I am wondering does `MyClass().my_fun1(input1)` instantiate an object of MyClass implicitly? Or MyClass() here is treated as a utility function class? If it is a utility function, why bother put it within a class? Or is it a static class? but it the `my_fun1` isn't marked as a static function?

Sorry I am coming from C++/Java background, so this is a bit strange to me ...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, it's been two days, if you found my answer helpful, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `MyClass().my_fun1(input1)` instantiats an object of MyClass first (since `MyClass()` calls the constructor) and then calls `my_fun1` function. 
In Python, there is no static class, but we do have static method and class method. You could find many good references for these concepts such as [HERE](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/) and [HERE](https://julien.danjou.info/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods/).

If you define a static method in `MyClass`, you will need to call it in the following manner:

```py
output = MyClass.my_static_method(input1)
```

Note that there is no `()` after `MyClass`, meaning you are not creating an object (instance).